# Neural Net One Hot Encoding WIth New Prediction Data

Tags: prediction, one-hot-encoding

This is a general question about One Hot Encoding and prediction i.e. not related to any package.  I have a Neural Net that was trained on data and some part of that was One Hot Encoded.  One of the fields in the data that was converted ended up with 1400+features.  It's all working OK and training well.  My question is how to get prediction data to work with the trained NN.  As an example, one of the fields in the training data is a site name field.  This One Hot Encodes to 1400 features due to the amount of different sites.  When the prediction data site names field is one hot encoded, it only ends up with 15 features as of course there are less sites and it fails due to missing features.  Anyone know how I deal with this?

SPG